# Use IplImage (and C APIs) in opencv 4

Tags: opencv, iplimage

In the [opencv github wiki](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Opencv4) it reads 'IplImage ... are mostly excluded from API and will be completely excluded in further OpenCV 4.x updates'. But in the 4.0.1 version there is still a include\opencv2\core\type_c.h file which contains the structure IplImage. Does it mean we can still use this data structure in opencv 4.0.1 [though it's not recommended to do so]?

Comment: The old structures have been deprecated ever since OpenCV 3.0 if I'm not mistaken. There's no benefit in using them. If you really need to use them, e.g. to support an old code base, then simple don't update to a newer version of OpenCV.

Comment: @StefanDragnev Thanks for your comment. The thing is I have a huge old code base but it is expected to be implemented with some new features in opencv4. It seems including the header above can solve the compilation problem -- just a work around.

Comment: Can you use it? Well, that depends on how big a gambler you are. The way I read it is "Some of the obsolete stuff may still be lying around, but you may as well consider it gone.", keeping in mind that it has been deprecated for ~4 years by now. If you need OpenCV 4, then updating the codebase to use the C++ API is inevitable. Putting it off just builds technical depth.